# How to solve $(x^2-2x)^2+4(x^2-2x)+3=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve $(x^2-2x)^2+4(x^2-2x)+3=0\,$? I tried

$$(x^2-2x)(x^2-2x+4)+3=0 \Longrightarrow (x^2-2x)(x^2-2x+4)=-3,$$ but couldn't continue. So that is why I came here to ask for some help, please. Thank you.

Lorie  Kirchner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT : Set $X=x^2-2x$. Then you'll have an equation of $X$.

Comment: i get X=-3 or X=-1 but when i do x²-2x=-3 i don't know how to continue??

Comment: Good job! Now you have $x^2-2x+3=0$.

Comment: @LorieKirchner Rearrange the equation to get $x^2-2x+3=0$ then use the Quadratic formula: If $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$

Comment: You are welcome! Enjoy studying math!

Comment: @LorieKirchner You're welcome! Glad it helps! :-)

Comment: @Adobe: Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}(x^2-2x)^2+4(x^2-2x)+3 & =(x^2-2x)^2+4(x^2-2x)+4-1 \\\,\\
& =(x^2-2x+2)^2-1 \\\,\\ 
& =(x^2-2x+1)(x^2-2x+3)\\\,\\ 
& =(x-1)^2(x^2-2x+3) 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Due to Viëta we have $x^2-2x=-1$ or $x^2-2x=-3$.  Clearly $x=1$ is the only (real) solution.